# How would Humans evolve to a natural predator?

Tags: evolution, humans

Humans, along with several other species, evolved on a very fertile planet. Humans became the dominant species, found most commonly on the planet. They lived in peace for hundreds of years.

Suddenly,a predator evolved. It was evolved to prey on Humans, and drove them into hiding.

Millenia later, Humans came out of hiding. They had evolved.

My question is:
How would they have evolved?

**EDIT**

The Humans were at current evolutionary stage before being forced into hiding.
They were forced into hiding into mountains and caves, without access to modern technology.

Comment: What's the stage of human evolution BEFORE they go into hiding relative to the predators?  It would be very very unlikely that any animal could naturally evolve to prey on modern humans: aside from viruses, prions, and bacteria etc. Where did they go into hiding? Caves? Mountains? Jungles? Different environments would contribute to different changes.

Comment: "_Suddenly,a predator evolved._" There's nothing sudden about evolution. "_Millenia later, Humans came out of hiding. They had evolved. How would they have evolved?_" maybe they became more stupid? Really though, it depends where they were hiding and why, doesn't it?

Comment: Humans *are* an apex predator. They have always been an apex predator. This is what we are. There has never been a predator who could out-predate us. When you say that a predator evolved to prey on humans, that *is* possible, but it would be quite a feat. We killed *all* wannabe apex predators who dared to compete with us.

Comment: without knowing the nature of the predator this is unanswerable.

Comment: "_They were forced into hiding into mountains and caves_" sooo... super predators who can outthink and outfight intelligent tool users, but are too dumb or have so shaky a theory of mind that they don't eat the stragglers?

Comment: "*They lived in peace for hundreds of years*" does not sound very human. Aspirationally wonderful, but not generally borne out by real human history.

Comment: Humans don't need millenia to *physically adapt* to new environments and theats -- we can *culturally adapt* much, much faster. Polar bears are huge and ferocious carnivores...and --according to the Inuit who have regularly hunted them for centuries-- delicious. We didn't need to evolve to survive in space, or the depths of the sea, or flying through the air: We organized ourselves (cultural adaptation) to make it possible another way.

Comment: @AlexP actually Humans are not an apex predator. We are a mid-range predator at best, and some felines were evolved to hunt us. Our Genus has been around for at least 200,000 years, yet you can only reasonably argue that we became capable of going toe to toe with an apex predator some time in the last 40,000 years. Not saying that we couldn't take on big game before then, but then again ant colonies have been taking on big game for 65+ million years, so not much of an accolade. And even now you really don't want to argue with a great white, or a hippo unprepared.

Comment: @Kain0_0: We hunted the mammoth. We exterminated the sabertooth tigers. We drove the cave bears and the cave lions extinct. In each and every ecosystem where we entered we came out on top. I am very curious about those felines who attempted to hunt us -- where are they? We are pack animals, we don't hunt hippos, or mammoths or lions *alone*, but hunt them we do. You may not have heard, but eventually we came to actually make very large territories *predator-free*, of course, free of *other* predators.

Comment: @AlexP: You can make similar statements for any invasive species. The species arrives the local flora/fauna don't know how to respond and generally kill off several local species. You can take a close look and break it up by herbivore/carnivore/omnivore and you'll find that omnivores have a disproportionate effect as an invasive species. Modern Man is endemic only to Africa. On every other continent we are an invasive omnivore. While right now with culture, technology, and numbers we are effective predators, that does not make us [apex predators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apex_predator).

Comment: Sabertooth tigers went extinct because they were specialized predators of mammoths.  When mammoths went away, the sabertooth tigers couldn’t adapt to hunting bunnies or people.  And, so ends the story of the sabertooth.  Human’s started their evolutionary climb as carrion eaters, opportunistic thieves, and bug munchers.

Answer (score 4):

First, you can't evolve in regards to a predator you have no contact with for millenia. It's just not how evolution works.

Second, any counter evolution from humans, would be driven relative to how the predator counters human "superiority". Is it killer Sharks, vampires, bacteria or something entirely else. Each would lead to a separate evolutionary response. No point in getting faster, if it jumps on us when we sleep.

Comment: You _can_ evolve random neutral stuff and discover later that it turns out to be useful (eg. all surviving humans now have grey hair. oh, and because of some pleiotropic effect, their flesh is toxic to the magical predator). Evolution is mostly random variables butting up against one another, after all.

Comment: @Starfish Prime That is not evolution, that is mutation or change. It's pedantic, but evolution is adaptation and change to better suit once environment.

Comment: Evolution is the accumulation of change. Better adaption to an environment is one thing that can help ensure than a change is kept. Don't conflate the two.

Answer (score 1):

**Here are the selective pressures that could drive evolution.**

Assuming the givens of the questions: 1: predator comes.  2: predator drives humans into hiding.  3: while in hiding humans evolve.  4: humans emerge.  How would they have evolved?

From point 2: you select for humans able to hide.  Humans inclined to stand their ground and fight, or humans which hide poorly will be eaten by the predator.  You have an initial [founder effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Founder_effect) because the new human population is a small, nonrandom (they are good hiders) subset of the initial population.  Some genes in the larger population will be lost during this stage.

From point 3:  Humans persist and reproduce while in hiding.  You do not specify if they are sneaking around and avoiding predators, or if they have decamped to someplace that the predators are not.  Either way is fine.

Evolution will be driven by selective pressures in their refuge where they are hiding.  If there is a marginal food source (e.g. tree leaves) and certain individuals have mutations allowing them to digest and use this food source better, those individuals will leave more children and their genes will spread.  If they are hiding in the same area as their predators, there will be strong selection for good hiding abilities because predators will catch poor hiders.

In sum the new humans will be

1:  Descended from humans who successfully hid when predators showed up.

2:  Descended from ancestors who successfully reproduced and raised children in the circumstances of their refuge.

---

Addendum: there might also have been an evolutionarily significant event among the humans that allowed the emergence of this predator.  For example in the story Day of the Triffids, there was some sort of meteor shower that rendered nearly everyone blind.  The triffids (aggressive plants) had been around before that event but were contained and farmed, and not a existential threat.  After the blindness apocalypse, the triffids emerged and could capitalize on the situation.